# Google AdMob 7 integration with cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, admob, cocoapods

I have spent hours on this and still no luck.

I have a library (which is a pod) and it's using Google AdMob 7 as a dependency, let's say that it's named MyLib

Now when I want to add pod 'MyLib' to project A, it'll install it alongside its dependencies which include Google AdMob 7.

The problem is: When I test the library project which contains its source files, it works just fine but when I compile project A, it doesn't compile and it gives me a compiler error on the import line

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;
```

which is in the MyLib source files.

To make it simpler

Project -> Contains a pod I wrote which is MyLib -> Using AdMob 7 as a pod

Any idea why it's happening?

**EDIT:**

If anyone is interested, the same now happens with Google maps after they converted it to a Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is interested or faced this problem, I know now why my end-point application couldn't notice the existence of Google Ad Mob pod inside my own pod.

I should have used spec.ios.vendored_frameworks in my pod spec cause now Google AdMob SDK and Maps SDK for iOS are provided as Frameworks in cocoapods so simply I added this to my pod spec for the library I wrote:

```
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Pods/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps.framework', 'Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.0.0/GoogleMobileAds.framework'
```

Comment: Hello @Aubada Talijo, Where to add this?

Comment: This is in your pod spec file

Comment: This is not related to your iOS project, this is the spec file of your pod library, the problem is all about cocoapods cause I have my own pod

Comment: Ok, so how to fix this?

Comment: Also please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485189/module-googlemobileads-not-found-in-ios    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469133/google-ad-mob-7-0-for-ios-updating-with-pod

Comment: These are not related to my issue, are you familiar with Cocoapods?

Comment: So you don't have my problem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74810/discussion-between-ranjit-and-aubada-taljo).

Answer (score 3):

There are two duplicate Google Ad Pods in Cocoa Pods:

[GoogleMobileAds](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleMobileAds) 20MB and contains only the framework

[Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK) 40MB contains the framework, samples and documentation.

Someone should update the cocoa pods description to make this clear rather than having the exact same Google Ad SDK description for both pods, which is really confusing.

Using the first pod containing the framework should solve your problem and import like this:

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
```

Comment: XCode says GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h not found

Comment: Did you follow the install guide at the link above? Replacing MyApp with your target.

Comment: Sorry. Had a brain fart. I put the pod in Test target no wonder it didn't work. Carry on people. Nothing to see here.