# Google Ad Mob 7.0 for iOS updating with Pod

Tags: ios, admob, cocoapods

I updated Pod file for Google Ad Mob using command "pod update", it got updated to 7.1.0 from 6.12.12,

But now when I run, it says

**"GADInterstial.h" file not found**, previously I had  no such issues.

Many suggest to use #import , because now the SDK is framework. But still the same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I fix a "GADInsterstitial.h" file not found... but it is in my list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842721/how-i-fix-a-gadinsterstitial-h-file-not-found-but-it-is-in-my-list)

Comment: No @Retro, In this case, he is not mentioning about Pods anywhere

Comment: add #import <GoogleMobileAds/GADInterstitial.h> to your .pch file

Comment: Xcode says 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/GADInterstitial.h' file not found

Comment: Set HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS Under your Project Build Setting will fix this problem