# AdMob 7.3.1 and Swift 2.0 - Module not found

Tags: ios, swift, module, admob, swift2

I have a problem using the Google AdMob Framework with Swift 2.0. I'm using AdMob for the first time so I do not know if the problem is with AdMob or Swift 2.0.

I have included the AdMob Framework and import it like that in my ViewController:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

The error I am getting is:

> No such Module GoogleMobileAds

A bridging header is also not working:

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
```

The Error:

> GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h file not found

How should I include AdMob? I have tested AdMob 6.12.2 and included it via the bridging header and it works.

The previous posts from other users didn't help me - there were no solutions for this problem.

Comment: This worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35653744/1890317

Answer (score 11):

Right click your project -> Show in Finder -> Create New Folder and copy GoogleMobileAds.framework after open project.

Select project-> Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> click "+" button -> click Add other.. button -> select GoogleMobileAds.framework and click Open button.

Restart your app then compile and import GoogleMobileAds to your swift view controller

Comment: restarting the app is what did it for me. if it does not work close it and reopen it. gets me every time.

Answer (score 10):

There are two steps to solve your problem:

1. Put the path of `GoogleMobileAds.framework` in Targets -> Build Settings `"Framework Search Path"`
2. Set **"No"** under Project -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode

Comment: Thanks for posting, I updated my Google Ad Mob framework, but never changed the search path.  That fixed it!

Answer (score 5):

Had this problem. 1st time user of Admob iOS as well.

This is how I solved it.

1. Go to your Project
2. Targes
3. Build Settings
4. Click 'All' and 'Levels' (so you get the same view as the screenshot)
5. On 'Search Paths' -> Go to 'Always Search User Paths' and change it to 'Yes' (see the boxed on screenshot) (mine was blank when I did mine)
6. On 'Framework Search Paths' clicked the option (boxed on screenshot) and add/change the setting to `$(inherited)`
7. Clean and Build your App

[image: Steps]

Got the solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26445806/2365714

Answer (score 2):

you can also install the googlemobileads with cocoa pods.
fist install cocoa pods and than add this pod
add:
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

in terminal use: pod install

cocoa pods page: https://cocoapods.org here they explain how to use cocoa pops if you don't know how it works

I hope this works (this worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I didn't add the framework without `Copy if necessary` checkbox. And I found that, in order to avoid the compiler error, you should check out all the followings:

- The `GoogleMobileAds.framework` is located in the project root
- In Targets | Build Settings | Search Paths | Framework Search Paths, you should find that the list includes `$(PROJECT_DIR)`, and if it doesn't exist, add it manually.

With these settings, you should find the app is compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Swift 3.0.  I had to update the Googleframeworks to 7.11 which fixed some errors in the main file.  I was getting this error though in the testing targets.  I made sure that the framework was checked in the Target Membership.

NOTE: Make sure to select the framework and then check the Target Dependency!

[image]

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of the suggested solutions without success, I copied the file GoogleMobileAds.framework to the root folder of the project (same location as xcodeproj file), then added it as explained in other solutions, and it magically built successfully :)