# No Such Module Locksmith

Tags: swift

Not sure why this is happening, I have included the file etc..

Project Navigation:

[image]

Target:
[image]

Embedded B:
[image]

Comment: Did you import it? import Locksmith

Comment: yes, that line is where the error is appearing.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @KapilaRamji "No Such Module Locksmith"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876363/admob-7-3-1-and-swift-2-0-module-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, clean build the project folder
(shift + alt + cmd + k)