# How do I integrate AdMob into an iOS app? Other tutorials do not seem to work with the latest updates

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate Google`s AdMob into my iOS app, using Xcode 7.2, Swift 2.0, and iOS 9.2. I followed the official tutorial on this: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start; and I have tried both methods: the streamlined method with CocoaPods, and manually using the SDK download.

In the streamlined method, I had a lot of trouble with CocoaPods, which nearly destroyed my entire Xcode project. This experience made me never use CocoaPods again. Unless you know a lot on CocoaPods, do not ask me to use them.

In the manual method, I am unable to import the framework into my code, although it is imported already into the project. I get the error: No such module 'GoogleMobileAds'. The framework is visible in the Project Navigator with other frameworks, in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries with other frameworks.

Due to this I am unable to use all of the code listed in the tutorial, and I have no code to show. If you are looking for any code related to integrating AdMob, it is in the tutorial. Please note I am a beginner in Swift, and I have no knowledge in Objective-C. Thanks.

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

Comment: Found out what the problem was myself. Answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the solution myself. I noticed that in the tutorial, there was an important section I promptly ignored:

> **Add other frameworks that the SDK requires** 
>  The SDK depends on the following iOS development frameworks which may not already be part
>   of your project:
>  AdSupport
>  AudioToolbox
>  AVFoundation
>   CoreGraphics
>  CoreMedia
>  CoreTelephony
>  EventKit
>   EventKitUI
>  MediaPlayer
>  MessageUI
>  StoreKit
>   SystemConfiguration

You must make sure these frameworks are already part of the project, since Admob depends on them. If anyone else is having similar issues as described above, try this, or read the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to solve your problem:

Put the path of GoogleMobileAds.framework in Targets -> Build Settings "Framework Search Path"

Set "**No**" under Project -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode

refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876363/admob-7-3-1-and-swift-2-0-module-not-found)