# Module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

Came across a topic with similar problem, but was unable to solve it.

Integrated Admob ads in Unity app for ios and loaded the project in XCode. Added framework GoogleMobileAds simply dragging it into the project window. Unfortunately when you build the project the error is displayed.

I tryed replace `GoogleMobileAds.h` on `#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>` in GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.h but it not help me.

Used Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v3.0.4
Xcode v. 7.3.1
Error: umbrella header googlemobileads h not found
[1 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeltZ.png)
[2 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j71Wr.png)

Comment: in project settings, set 'Enble C/C++ module' to YES

Comment: Nothing failed. I added all, except for Sqlite (missing in Xcode, I don't know where to download). With 4 frameworks still have this 2 errors/
I checked C++ module - it works but not compiling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485189/module-googlemobileads-not-found-in-ios

Comment: Did you finally found a solution to your problem ? I'm in the same spot and can't find any working solution.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxO_rcMxGU4, here is a summary:

1. Download googlemobileadssdkios.zip from https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/download
2. Unzip file. Go to Project Navigator View. Move the unzip file inside the Framework folder.
3. Build the code, if it doesn't work then substitute the string that gives error with

   - (void)loadRequest:(GADRequest *)request withAdUnitID:(NSString *)adUnitID userID:(NSString *)userID {

[self.rewardBasedVideo loadRequest:request withAdUnitID:adUnitID];
}

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added the following libraries

- Sqlite
- Core data
- System Configuration
- libz
- adSupport

add these libraries in the "Frameworks and Libraries" in Project settings

Comment: This should be done BEFORE adding GoogleMobileAds.framework or after? Or doesn't matter?

Comment: it doesn't matter and also add -ObjC flag in "Other Linker Flags" in build settings

Comment: plus that, what u said?

Comment: Nothing failed. I added all, except for Sqlite (missing in Xcode, I don't know where to download). 

With 4 frameworks still have this 2 errors