# GoogleMobileAds (Admob) framework not detected in Xcode 9 - linker error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, admob, xcode9

I got linker error GADInterstitial referenced from. Undifined symbols for architecture arm64

I used latest admob framework GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.24.0

See attach image. How to fix it for iOS 11 ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Answer (score 2):

Its Xcode 9 Bug. Once you add framework in Xcode side bar, it never auto adds in 'Link Binary with Libraries' section.

Solution is simple. Just drag framework in Xcode Side bar to Link Binary section. See attach image.
[image]